# How to select rows by comparing two sums on child tables, without subqueries?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a schema that looks like the following:

```
Invoices:        | id | ... |
InvoicePayments: | id | invoice_id | amount_cents | ... |
LineItems:       | id | invoice_id | unit_price_cents | quantity | ... |
```

and I am looking to find unpaid invoices, that is, Invoices who have a sum of amount_cents from InvoicePayments that is less than the sum of (quantity * unit_price) from LineItems. I was able to accomplish this with two sub queries, like:

```
SELECT prices.id FROM (
  SELECT invoices.id, sum(invoice_payments.amount_cents) as paid
  FROM invoices
  LEFT JOIN invoice_payments ON invoice_payments.invoice_id = invoices.id
  GROUP BY invoices.id
) payments JOIN (
  SELECT invoices.id, sum(line_items.quantity * line_items.unit_price_cents) as price
  FROM invoices
  LEFT JOIN line_items ON line_items.invoice_id = invoices.id
  GROUP BY invoices.id
) prices
ON payments.id = prices.id
WHERE paid < price OR paid IS NULL;
```

However, I am using ActiveRecord and would like something simpler that could be translated into Arel statements; additionally, I would like to use this as a reusable scope, so I could apply additional constraints, such as finding Invoices that were unpaid on a certain date, by filtering out InvoicePayments that are newer than that date.

Is there a way to accomplish this without subqueries so that I can use this more easily with Rails and apply flexible filters?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to define views to encapsulate the subqueries you have defined above, and to then define read only models on them.

They can then associate with the invoice model, and give you the opportunity to simplify your syntax considerably.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    i.id
    COALESCE(SUM(l.quantity * l.unit_price_cents),0) - COALESCE(SUM(p.amounts_cents),0) as UnpaidBalance
FROM
    invoices i
    LEFT JOIN invoice_payments p
    ON i.id = p.invoice_id
    AND p.DateColumn <= '2016-01-30'
    LEFT JOIN line_items l
    ON i.id = l.invoice_id
GROUP BY
    i.id
HAVING
    COALESCE(SUM(p.amounts_cents),0) < COALESCE(SUM(l.quantity * l.unit_price_cents),0)
```

Especially with the addition of window functions to many relational database management systems such as postgressql you rarely need to sub queries like that anymore.  When using left joins aggregate functions will ignore the null values so by simply combining your left joins into the same query you can still get to your desired result.

You may notice the use of table alias which makes it a little easier to read and a lot less writing of code for you.  you can define an alias by typing one just after then table name in your query.  I did include `p.DateColumn <= some date`.  you can parameratize the query to pass a variable their and test if it is null and choose current date time if you want as of today.